# How can I look for a keyword in a Scribd document?

Tags: pdf, scribd

I am reading this [book on Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/83889078/How-Eskimos-Keep-Their-Babies-Warm-And-Other-Adventures-in-Parenting-from-Argentina-to-Tanzania-and-everywhere-in-between). How can I look for a keyword in this document?

Answer (score 1):

The first portion of my answer has nothing to do with your question, but I thought I'd mention it as an FYI.

According to the support desk at Scribd <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> is only supported if "the document's publisher has allowed copying/pasting from the document."  This is a bug they are currently trying to resolve.

Your best bet is to go to "Edit" or "Tools" in your web browser's menu and click "Find" to search for a particular keyword.

Comment: Thanks, searching using the find function of the browser didn't work, but good to know that Scribd's `ctrl + f` isn't supposed to always work (they should probably add some warning in their UI when search is disabled).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt What web browser did you use (I used Firefox)?  I had to wait until the entire document loaded before finding a keyword in the document, which was ensured by scrolling through the entire document to see that all pages loaded.  Counter intuitive I know, but it works to extent.  Glad to have helped!